# How can I make vertical blinds with wood vanes?

Tags: plywood, blinds

I was thinking of 1/8" Luaun or baltic birch.  I would like to use a clear coat or dye-stain plus varnish.

Yes there are a raft of types of plywood. Other suggestions welcome.

By dimensionally stable I'm most concerned about warp and twist.

Exposure is full sun for 2/3 of the day through patio door windows.

I'm looking for a combination of wood plus finish that may work for this.

I have to replace the blinds anyway.  The old vert blind mechanism works fine.  Occurred to me that I could replace them with vertical slats of wood.  Now I've seen horizontal venetian blinds made with wood, but I don't know what they did to make them warp proof.

At one point venetian blinds were made of wood.  How did they deal with the warp and twist problem?

Comment: Depends. "1/8 inch plywood" is a class of products. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Applying finish will help. Also, where they hang and how much sun and humidity they get exposed to. You could also glue a few perpendicular slats that would help keep them flat, say one the top, one at the bottom and one in the middle.